# Different text-decoration on the same commandButton

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need put two different text-decoration on the same commandButton (Primefaces). My comandButton have the next code:

```
<p:commandButton id="nodosUp#{m.id}" 
 value="#{estadoDashBoard.numNodosActivos}&#10;UP" 
 styleClass="btnEstado #{estadoDashBoard.numNodosActivos eq 0 ? 'btnEstadoNeutro' : 'btnEstadoActivos'}"
 disabled="#{estadoDashBoard.numNodosActivos eq 0 ? 'true' :'false'}"
 style="white-space: pre;"/>
```

And this  is the result:

[image]

I want to change the size of number "2" but keep the size of "UP" as it's now.

Comment: The only way this is possible is to see if you can add/use html in the value of the commandButton. Search for that in StackOverflow. If that works, it is all just 'css'. I doubt this will be possible. So the answer by BalusC is most likely the right one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible in HTML, let alone in JSF as it's "just" a HTML code generator.

Replace it by `<p:commandLink>` which generates a HTML `<a>` element allowing much more markup freedom as it allows children.

E.g.

```
<p:commandLink ...>
    <span class="number">2</span>
    <br />
    <span class="text">UP</span>
</p:commandLink>
```

Comment: Any suggestions to make it look a commandLink than a commandButton?

Comment: If I replace my commandButton for a commandLink the appearance it's different. It does not have the green square (only it's green the background text), the align text it's different, and only works if I click the link .

Comment: Oh you just have a CSS problem. This is not related to JSF. To solve the described problem, make it an inline-block element. For the remainder, please ask a new question to [css] users while providing HTML source (and thus not JSF source). In the meanwhile, I suggest taking time apart to learn some basic CSS: http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/beginner/